# ayuda en función para comparar la fecha del sistema con una fecha elegida en un calendarView

Tags: android, android-studio, calendar

necesito una función para validar que la fecha elegida de un caledar view sea una fecha posterior al día en que se haga un registro y que si no se cumple esto no me deje continuar con un boton, ya tengo la parte de la función pero me falla que al inicio no me compara nada si no que hasta que aprieto el boton y vuelvo a elegir fechas en mi calendario entonces si lo hace, este seria el codigo

```
private  void validarCalendario(CalendarView calendarView){

        calendario.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendario, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                Calendar calendarNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                int monthDay =calendarNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month = calendarNow.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = calendarNow.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                String hora = horario.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String day = String.valueOf(monthDay);
                String mes = String.valueOf(month+1);
                String año = String.valueOf(year);

                i1 = i1+1;
                String dayC = String.valueOf(i2);
                String mesC = String.valueOf(i1);
                String añoC = String.valueOf(i);

                try{
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    Date date1 = sdf.parse(day + "-" + mes + "-" + año);
                    Date date2 = sdf.parse(dayC + "-" + mesC + "-" + añoC);
                    if(date2.before(date1) || date1.equals(date2) ){
                        continuarFlag = false;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"La cita no se puede agendar el mismo dia del registro o anterior a este", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        textMessage = "La fecha de su cita es el " + i2 + "" + "/" + i1 + "" + "/" + i + " con un horario de " + hora;

                    }

                }
                catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

ya en el boton mando a llamar a la funcion de validar en la cual se valida este calendario, pero hasta despues del primer clic en el boton

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido bien, tienes un error de compresión en el flujo de tu programa.

Si es el botón el que llama a la función `validarCalendario(CalendarView calendarView)`, es normal que hasta el momento no te valide nada pues es en esa función donde se define el evento `onSelectedDayChange`. Lo que te ocurre es:

- Cuando arranca tu Activity, el evento `onSelectedDayChange` aun no se ha registrado.
- El usuario elige una fecha, la que quiera.
- Cuando el usuario pulsa el botón, registras el evento `onSelectedDayChange`, pero nada ocurre, pues el usuario está pulsando el botón y no seleccionando alguna fecha.
- El usuario vuelve a cambiar la fecha (por segunda vez) y ahora si, hay un evento registrado.

Lo que tienes que hacer es registrar el evento `onSelectedDayChange` en el `onCreate` de tu Activity, así estará *activo* para cuando el usuario vaya a cambiar la fecha.

Comment: si en el onCreate solo dejo 
 calendario.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendario, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }
        });
entonces en mi función private  void validarCalendario(CalendarView calendarView){
       
    }
como podría validar mi calendario ?

Comment: tienes un `continuarFlag` que estableces a `false` cuando la validación no es correcta, aunque te falta establecerlo a `true` cuando si.

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor hacer la comparacion de las fechas directamente con `long`.
Puedes obtener el valor `long` de la fecha actual de esta forma:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
long hoy = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Ó de esta otra forma:

```
long hoy_b = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Suponiendo una fecha posterior a hoy, digamos 3 meses:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,3);
```

Obtienes el long así:

```
long despues = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Siempre las fechas futuras en long son mayores a la actual (hoy).

Comparas así:

```
String resultado="";
if(despues > hoy){ 
            resultado = "despues es MAYOR que hoy"; 
        }else {
            resultado = "despues es MENOR que hoy";
            //tu lógica para el botón
        }
 }
```

Lo puedes verificar en el LogCat, en long y en formato de fecha:

```
Log.i("FECHA HOY: ", String.valueOf(hoy)+"  "+new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(hoy));
Log.i("FECHA HOY_B: ", String.valueOf(hoy_b)+"  "+new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(hoy_b));
Log.i("FECHA DESPUES: ", String.valueOf(despues)+"  "+new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(despues));
Log.i("FECHA RESULTADO", resultado);
```

En el logcat verás esto:

```
I/FECHA HOY: 1528576097231  09/06/2018    
I/FECHA HOY_B: 1528576097231 09/06/2018
I/FECHA DESPUES: 1536524897231  09/09/2018
I/FECHA RESULTADO: despues es MAYOR que hoy
```